# Distribution sampling from a trajectory

Tags: statistics, stochastic-processes

Consider a sequence of random variables $\{X_1, X_2,.., X_n\}$ corresponding to regular measurements of a single observable over time obtained from a laboratory or computer experiment.

Assume that the signal they form is sampling some underlying stationary distribution for the observable $X$ (like a Markov Chain would do for example), but that a priori the covariance $Cov(X_i, X_{i+k}) \neq 0$ unless $k > k_{\rm threshold} $.

My colleague states that if we want to characterise this distribution by building an empirical Cumulative Distribution Function (eCDF) we can do it using every single $X$-value in the sequence.

I am leaning towards thinking that the sampling must be made over a subset of the data spaced enough (larger than $k_{\rm threshold}$) so that each data point is mostly uncorrelated with the others.
This is to avoid the problem of autocorrelation or pseudo-replication [see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudoreplication) . I am aware that it leads to problems in the estimation of the variance of the mean (when not corrected with autocorrelation data) [see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Markov_chain_central_limit_theorem&action=edit&section=3) and so I am not sure it is reliable for a more complete statistical picture of the distribution we want to sample like an eCDF.

I have 3 questions but which all revolve around the same issue presented above.

1. I have actually some difficulty finding any clear literature on this subject, even in the computer simulation texts I have consulted. From my own professional experience, people have various rules of thumbs and rarely compute averages or distributions from every step, but the reasoning put forward behind such practices can be as remote (to my query) as storage space. **Is anyone aware of mathematics/statitics/computational physics literature about this?**
2. **If my worry is unfounded, can someone explain to me why?**
3. **or if my worry is founded, is there a way to justify the pragmatic approach of my colleague of using all data at hand? By estimating the error perhaps?**

Comment: When you pass the sum of independent spectral components $\sum_k \tilde {A}_k e^{ \mathfrak j \omega_k t}$, the rv. $\tilde A_k$ are independent, through a bandpass filter and then observe the time samples, those filtered samples are all correlated although the underlying process is completely random, the filtering itself creates correlations. To learn about what has gone in I would never throw samples away.

Comment: @hyportnex Thanks. I am not talking about throwing samples away. I am asking about a reliable way of sampling the underlying distribution without biases owing (possibly?) to the correlated samples.

Comment: That depends on the process and the filter.  For example, if you know that the underlying stochastic process is normal (Gaussian) and you know the bandpass filter, say, that creates the correlations then sampling at rate twice the bandwidth (Nyquist rate) gives you uncorrelated, in fact, independent,  samples.

Comment: CDF may not contain all the info you need, to have a clear picture of your system. Have you tried to identify your system? As an example, if you know that you can model it as a Markov process, and you can divided the continuous state in a finite number of intervals, you could try to identify the model learning the probability transition matrix

Comment: @hyportnex In general, I do not know the underlying stochastic process. It comes from the output of a complex simulation of thousands of particles. Is the existence of the/a Nyquist rate guaranteed for all processes with simply a different number in front of the bandwidth?

Comment: @basics I am looking at the CDF not because I want a complete picture of my system (I am the one running the system) but because I want to compare this CDF to another one predicted by a specific theory.

Comment: That samples are independent when taken at the Nyquist rate holds for a wide-sense stationary Gaussian process, and it follows from that uncorrelated normal random variates are also independent. There are several spectrum estimation techniques that you may try but they need some kind of underlying model, such as the so-called autoregressive estimator, see a few [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_density_estimation)

Comment: there are two other SE fora dealing with this subject where you would more likely get professional help than here https://dsp.stackexchange.com/ and https://dsp.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Just a very partial answer. If you have many points clustered near a single X and the rest scattered, you will have a very good estimate of the trajectory near X and a less good estimate elsewhere.

If you have more than enough data, discarding some of it will still give you enough information about the trajectory. Possibly you might introduce a bias by discarding similar points.

If you have less data or a lot of noise, you need to be more careful about how you handle the statistics.